What is the status of philosophical literature of quantum state realism?
According to the SEP article here, a framework was introduced that seemed to provide some evidence against anti realistic options of quantum mechanics. The relevant quotes are as follows:

Harrigan and Spekkens (2010) have introduced a framework for discussing these issues. In their terminology, a complete specification of the physical properties is given by the ontic state of a system. An ontological model posits a space of ontic states and associates, with any preparation procedure, a probability distribution over ontic states. A model is said to be
ψ
-ontic if the ontic state uniquely determines the quantum state; that is, if there is a function from ontic states to quantum states (this includes both cases in which the quantum state also completely determines the physical state, and cases, such as hidden-variables theories, in which the quantum state does not completely determine the physical state). In their terminology, models that are not
ψ
-ontic are called
ψ
-epistemic. If a model is not
ψ
-ontic, this means that it is possible for some ontic states to be the result of two or more preparations that lead to different assignments of pure quantum states; that is, the same ontic state may be compatible with distinct quantum states.


This gives a nice way of posing the question of quantum state realism: are there preparations corresponding to distinct pure quantum states that can give rise to the same ontic state, or, conversely, are there ontic states compatible with distinct quantum states? Pusey, Barrett, and Rudolph (2012) showed that, if one adopts a seemingly natural independence assumption about state preparations—namely, the assumption that it is possible to prepare a pair of systems in such a way that the probabilities for ontic states of the two systems are effectively independent—then the answer is negative; any ontological model that reproduces quantum predictions and satisfies this Preparation Independence assumption must be a
ψ
-ontic model.


The Pusey, Barrett and Rudolph (PBR) theorem does not close off all options for anti-realism about quantum states; an anti-realist about quantum states could reject the Preparation Independence assumption, or reject the framework within which the theorem is set; see discussion in Spekkens (2015): 92–93. See Leifer (2014) for a careful and thorough overview of theorems relevant to quantum state realism, and Myrvold (2020) for a presentation of a case for quantum state realism based on theorems of this sort.


Considering that the quote answers the title question, what is the question? Myrvold's paper is literally titled On the Status of Quantum State Realism.
